# Rails link_to static pages issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I don't know an awful lot about Rails and I've inherited this project. For the past few days I've been trying to get my head around, 'link_to', and 'routes.rb'. This stuff is driving me mad - I've spent the whole day looking at it, pasting bits of code into bare projects, where it works..but I just don't understand the error I'm getting here, or how to go about solving it, so if you have any ideas....

In my page _signed_in_header.html.erb I have:

```
<a href="../staticpages/faq">FAQ</a>
```

In my routes.rb I have:

```
get "staticpages/faq"
```

I know this is set up correct, because when I start a sample project from scratch, it works.

But in this particular project I've inherited I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Staticpages#faq

Showing /home/christophecompaq/Populisto/app/views/layouts/_signed_in_header.html.erb    where line #48 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #48):

45: 
46:       <div class='search-box'>
47:       <%= simple_form_for @review, :url => search_index_path, :method => :post,   :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
48: 
49:         <%= f.input :search_ids, :collection => @data, :as => :grouped_chosen, 
50:                     :group_method => :last, :prompt => false,
51:                     :input_html => { :class => 'span5', :multiple => true }, 
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb,     app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/christophecompaq/Populisto

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/_signed_in_header.html.erb:48:in  `_app_views_layouts__signed_in_header_html_erb___586079249_69970641688720'
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:1:in  `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__1905506502_69970640142220'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in  `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1868096314_69970642536740'
```

Edit: I was asked to show my review controller code, so here it goes:

```
class ReviewsController < FrontEndController
respond_to :html, :json

before_filter :with_google_maps_api

def index
@review = Review.new
end

def create
@review = Review.create((params[:review] || {}).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
if @review.save
  redirect_to landing_page, :notice =>    I18n.t('write_review.review_successfully_created')
else
  render :action => :index
end
end

def show
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
if @review.update_attributes(params[:review])

else
  render :edit
end
end

def destroy
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
@review.destroy
end

def repost
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
@review.repost(current_user)
end

def reject
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
current_user.reject @review
end

end
```

Anyway, if you have any ideas what could be wrong, I'd be delighted to know....Thanks.

Christophe.

Comment: Most likely, a template is trying to access a variable (probably an instance variable) that has not been assigned. Based on the included source, I'd probably guess that `@review` is the offending variable.

Answer (score 4):

in your route file, use this code

```
get "staticpages/faq", :as => 'faq_page'
```

The 'as' will generate 2 helper functions: `faq_page_url` and `faq_page_path` that you can use in your code

Comment: sorry, am I supposed to change the code elsewhere too, as well as the routes.rb file?

Comment: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class -> this says that your @review is empty. read the error description, go to the line mentioned, review your code around this line, don't hesitate to use puts to echo your variables in your server's console, use the debugger if you need, and find why @review is empty (did you mispell it?)

Comment: Yes, I was just showing you how to write a named route, you have to adapt it to your code, and fix elsewere you use paths in you app

Comment: I second what @BenjaminSinclaire just said.  And while you are at it, it might be helpful to post your controller code that is being used to generate your view. `@review` is an instance variable that is most likely being created in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

i hope this will help, i think we have the same issue but i've managed to fix this using this:

in my routes.rb

```
match 'pages/:action', :controller => "pages"
```

and in my view:

```
= link_to "About", {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening during rendering of the layout template, not the controller view.

If you're testing the faq page you'll be hitting the StaticpagesController, not the ReviewController you pasted right? And presumably StaticpagesController does not set @review... hence your exception.

So either try wrapping the search box code in a conditional like:

```
<% if @review %>
  ... put your review search form here ...
<% end %>
```

or if the search is supposed to present on all pages, ensure it's populated on all pages. Maybe add a `before_filter` on your base controller class with something like

class ApplicationController < ....

```
 before filter :ensure_review_set

 private

 def ensure_review_set
    @review ||= Review.new
 end
```

end

The search form is also referencing `@data` if the `search_ids` field. That will also need to be initialised by any controllers using this layout.

More generally, if your version of rails supports it, I'd very very highly recommend the [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gem for quickly debugging errors such as this.

Comment: Cheers jbw, I'll look at your suggestions in detail later today, and get back to you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, just saw your question with this sudden weekly email Stack Exchange keep sending me. Can't remember if you solved my problem - I'll check - but +1 for the effort!